# Select Same Element on Second List By Order of Second List

Tags: c#, list, linq, linked-list

I have a two list of character arrays:

```
char[] charA = new char[] { 'a', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'a' };
char[] charB = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
```

Now I want to get all the same element and get the same arrangement like on second list (**arrangement is a, b, c, d**):

```
var final = charA.Where(x => charB.Any(y => y == x)).ToArray();
```

The result of this is:

```
'a', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'a'
```

**But what I want is the arrangement on the second list using LINQ:**

```
'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve it is to select from the second array and join to it the first:

```
var result = from b in charB
             join a in charA on b equals a into c
             from a in c
             select a;
```

You can also achieve it joining `charA` to `charB` and using the `Select` overload that receives the item's index:

```
var result = from a in charA
             join b in charB.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }) on a equals b.item
             orderby b.index
             select a;
```

---

A little note about your implementation: see you can use `Contains` instead of `Any`:

```
charA.Where(x => charB.Contains(x))
```

Comment: It works! But what is the difference of using Contains and Any? I am using Any most of the time, is there any special case I should Contains vs Any if getting the same element on two list?

Comment: I was trying to get this in LINQ's Method Syntax, can you add how it will be in Method Syntax?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr - if you want to check if a collection holds a given item (as in this case) then `Contains` is better. If you want to check if the collection contains at least one item containing a certain predicate then use `Any`

Comment: @GiladGreen `Contains()` lacks flexibility why would you prefer it over `Any()`? Of course we are not talking about a hashmap, just a regular collection where both operations would be O(n) time complexity.

Comment: @Deadzone - because such flexibility is not needed. It is a defined condition that is needed - to see if the other collection contains the current object. If you look at the `Any` you'll see `x == y` - meaning "I want objects that are present in the second collection" or in other words - objects that are contained in the second collection.

Comment: @GiladGreen That's one usage of `Any`, but that's not the main use of the function, you can read `Any` in the following way: *Does any item of this collection matches my boolean expression?*, where `Contains` would read *Does this collection contains 'x'?*, see the difference? The former has much more uses than the latter, you can implement Strategy Pattern using delegates but you cant do it with pure values, it also gives you consistency because you can do all sorts of operations using one method instead of two.

Comment: @Deadzone - " see the difference" - of course I see the difference. And that is why I decided to suggest `Contains` - because the need is to compare `char`s

Comment: Yes. I wasn't able to accept it immediately due to time restrictions @GiladGreen Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using method syntax:

```
char[] charA = new char[] { 'a', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'a' };
char[] charB = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
var result = charA.Where(x => charB.Contains(x)).OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(charB, x));
```

Firstly, `Where` is used to filter out values that are not in `charB`. Without this, elements that are not in `charB` would end up at the beginning of `result`. Then, the remaining collection is simply sorted by using `Array.IndexOf` which returns the index of each element of `charA` in `charB`. This is not optimal, but a really short solution.